# Reference Temp Column in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

I have a temp column called `CFADTemp` that I am trying to use in a inner join to help me match up data from a different table.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3
FROM 
    CFAddress A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         CustomerNumber, AddressType, 
         MAX((CASE 
                 WHEN AddressType = '3' THEN '4'
                 WHEN AddressType = '1' THEN '3'
                 WHEN AddressType = '4' THEN '2'
                 WHEN AddressType = '2' THEN '1'
              END) AS CFADTemp
    FROM 
        CFAddress
    GROUP BY 
        CustomerNumber, AddressType) B ON B.CustomerNumber = A.CustomerNumber 
                                       AND...
```

I need to join with `CFADTemp` and with the case when situation, not only with `CustomerNumber`

Does anyone know how to use a temp field to help make this inner join work so I can get the data I need?

Comment: Please post the entire query, and fill in the ellipsis `...` with the actual code.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in your code `max((` should be `max(`

Answer (score 1):

Reference the name:

```
...
) B on B.CustomerNumber = A.CustomerNumber AND B.CFADTemp = A.AddressType
```

If you need the same `3=>4,1=3,4=>2,2=>1` mapping for `A.AddressType`, you'll need another `CASE` expression.

Comment: I try to use this statement ON B.CustomerNumber = A.CustomerNumber 
                                       AND B.CFADTemp = CASE 
                 WHEN AddressType = '3' THEN '4'
                 WHEN AddressType = '1' THEN '3'
                 WHEN AddressType = '4' THEN '2'
                 WHEN AddressType = '2' THEN '1'
              END

Comment: but still not match